# Which JavaScript framework can be best used for newspaper website, ImageMap or Something better?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, javascript

I want to make a website like http://www.nawaiwaqt.com.pk/E-Paper/Lahore/2011-07-25/page-5

or http://www.etemaaddaily.com/, i want to upload a full fledge image from backend, and when we hover over sections, it should display images on clicking and should be highlighted, just like in the above examples.

But there is a problem, if we use ImageMap Javascript for this, then we have to define coordinates hardcoded, which is absurd, a layman cant do this stuff, he needs a drag n drop or some easy way to define his articles and section area, please let me know do you know any JS framework which can do so, and yes project is in asp.net

Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool Image Map which is part of the software GIMP to create the image maps and generate the necessary markup:

[Create Image Maps with GIMP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153937/Create-Image-Maps-with-GIMP/?display=Mobile)